# Does createScaledBitmap() use px or dp?

Tags: android

When specifying the width and height of your scaled Bitmap, is the method asking for pixels or density-independent pixels?

I have a 240dp device and when scaling an image to 240x240, the image is barely half the screen size. I was expecting it to be full screen. Does this mean the method uses pixels?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it uses px.  You can obtain the size of the screen, and call createScaledBitmap(screenWidth ... )

Comment: I've figured that is the way to go. Thanks!